# How do I write a batch file to uninstall an application and install a new version of it?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am using a CAD application which will have monthly updates. For updating, we need to uninstall the current version and install new version which will come with the new patch.

Can we do that?

Comment: I think you left the caps lock on

Comment: string.downcase to the rescue..

Comment: @user73628: You have asked 21 questions, 19 och which have been answered, but you have not accepted an answer to any of them. Is that because you do not know how to do it, or because you have not found any answers useful yet? In the first case, see here: http://privat.rejbrand.se/howtoaccept.html

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at using a proper installer to do the job: you can use something free like [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) to help you build something to meet your needs.  It will take a little up-front work but the results will be far more professional and robust that a batch file.

Comment: Inno Setup is a great free installer. Download: http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php